# How do I fix the bug where there are no available options when choosing a household?

Tags: mods, the-sims-3

I've been playing *Sims 3*, lately with the Overwatch mod to help clean the game up as it was getting very sluggish. I came across a bug where I bought a coffee machine, but my sim wasn't able to interact with it. When I entered build/buy mode, I couldn't interact with the machine then either, so I tried to move the counter it sat on. That quickly became unresponsive too, so I saved and quit my game to restart it.

When coming back to the game, I get a popup saying "Some objects could not be loaded and were replaced". But when I go to "Choose Household", none of the houses in the town (Appaloosa Plains) are available to select, including my own.

[image: screenshot of the above-described issue]
[image: screenshot of the above-described issue]

Is there a way around this situation to get back to my sim? Or at the very least, a way to take my sim as he is, and reinsert him into the town? I don't have him saved into the library.

Comment: At this point I'd be more concerned that you appeared to have hosed your game assets somehow and try to fix that ... Unless you just want to preserve this one character before nuking your install and starting fresh?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that's a new term to me - what do you mean by "hosed"? Ideally I'd like to at least save this sim, and if I have to restart everything else after that, so be it.